# '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
    reference.child("StoryList").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let story = Story()
        story.name = snapshot.key
        self.storyArray.append(story)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I run this inside viewDidLoad()
The whole console text is:

2017-12-26 19:53:16.034777+0300 StoryMakers[5216:2326957] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40005000 started
2017-12-26 19:53:16.046994+0300 StoryMakers[5216:2326957] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
2017-12-26 19:53:16.227775+0300 StoryMakers[5216:2326960] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-12-26 19:53:16.227820+0300 StoryMakers[5216:2326960] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-12-26 19:53:17.635435+0300 StoryMakers[5216:2326934] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''***

First throw call stack:
(0x185daa364 0x184ff0528 0x100f93824 0x100f6f4a0 0x100e771b4 0x100e77858 0x18f28bae8 0x18f28b6c0 0x18f40eb1c 0x18f331c4c 0x18f331890 0x18f331790 0x18f288f00 0x189ded998 0x189df1b20 0x189d5e36c 0x189d85b90 0x189d869d0 0x185d51edc 0x185d4f894 0x185d4fe50 0x185c6fe58 0x187b1cf84 0x18f2ef67c 0x100e82ab0 0x18578c56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**And it shows "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" inside AppDelegate.swift.**

**If I remove self.tableView.reloadData() it runs without errors.**
**If I print(snapshot.key) it prints:**

*Crow Doggy Google Test Ворон Кот*
to the console.

Comment: for one thing, I believe that you should run `reloadData` on the main queue but I am not familiar with firebase therefore I am not sure on which queue is the `observe` closure called. It can be also connected to something you are doing in your table data source.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that the fragment you shared throws this error, since the only call to `child()` uses a hard-coded (and legal) value. Are you sure there isn't another call to `child()` where you pass in a dynamic value, e.g a variable?

Comment: Post your data structure and the rest of the view controller's code. Where is your ref defined?

Comment: Add an exception break point so you can see the exact like that is throwing this error. Look at the answer to this question for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527213/firebase-child-must-be-a-non-empty-string-and-not-contain

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help. Especially to DoesData. I found what to fix in code with exception break point.